# NWjs version of Bad Time Simulator not playing bgm

Tags: javascript, html, audio, ogg, nwjs

I found a [game](https://jcw87.github.io/c2-sans-fight/) online, or which the source code is [here](https://github.com/Jcw87/c2-sans-fight/tree/gh-pages), and I wanted to mod it. However, after modding it online on Github for a while, I was being driven crazy, by the github pages load time and my browser cache, which seemed to defy all attempts at deletion.
Finally, I attempted to use NWjs to load it. But, now the audio doesn't play at all. How do I fix this?
Note, the sounds, like the ding and select noise play, but *not* the bgm. All of them are .ogg files.
I'm using windows 10.
Another note, I pushed my version to Github and then checked out the gh-pages, which worked. So it's probably a problem with NWjs or my computer or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared all things I could find, so `~/AppData/Local/nwjs` and `~AppData/Local/<projectname>` and `~/AppData/Roaming/<projectname>` all got deleted, then I ran it again and it worked.

EDIT: It seems that I have to re-delete the cache files again and again before each launch. Guess I'll write a python script to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need proprietary codecs.

Easiest way:

- Switch to the latest version supported by the prebuilts (currently 0.55.0)

  - https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt/releases
- Download the version you need, unzip, and place it with your NW.js files.

More details:

- https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Developers/Enable%20Proprietary%20Codecs/

Comment: I tried this, but it gave an error. I then noticed that I was using a newer version, so I downgraded NWjs and it run without crashing. However, this hasn't fixed the problem and there was already an `ffmpeg.dll` in my NWjs installation.

Comment: @Cuboid_Raptor every NW.js build has `ffmpeg.dll` included, but they don't include the proprietary codecs unless you build them like Jared mentioned.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing this out, but I replaced the old `ffmpeg.dll` with the new one, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Also, in the second page @Jaredcheeda gave, it mentions that the current `ffmpeg.dll` already supports vorbis, and ogg. All audio files, including the sounds and bgm are already in that format.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded [the files you linked](https://github.com/Jcw87/c2-sans-fight/archive/refs/heads/gh-pages.zip). I put that folder inside another called "game". Made a `game/package.json` file with this:

```json
{
  "main": "c2-sans-fight-gh-pages/index.html",
  "name": "example"
}
```

Downloaded the Win 64 SDK version of NW.js v0.55.0.

- http://dl.nwjs.io/v0.55.0/nwjs-sdk-v0.55.0-win-x64.zip

Dumped those files into the `game` folder so `nw.exe` was next to `package.json` and then ran it, and it worked fine. All audio played normally. I did not need to pull in the modified ffmpeg at all.

Comment: Huh. This is exactly what I did, except for the fact that you used SDK instead of Normal. Maybe this has a difference?

Comment: I downloaded the linked SDK version of NWjs and did this. I also cleared my NWjs AppData folder, in case there was some setting I had unwittingly activated that blocked bgm or smth. Still didn't work.

Comment: another probably worth noting is that I had already been modding it before, and it worked at the time. Then, the music disappeared, then the sounds, and I gave up. Now, I came back to the project, and while the sounds are back the music is not.